# Did “find” rhyme with “joined” in the 18th century?

Tags: pronunciation, rhymes

I notice that in Alexander Pope's poem, [An Essay on Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_on_Criticism) (1711), lines 669-70, there is the following couplet:

*In grave Quintilian’s copious works we find

The justest rules and clearest method join’d*

So, I take it that to Pope, the words "find" and "join'd" rhymed. Of course, today these words do not rhyme. Find rhymes with "kind" and "rind" and "bind", whereas, "join" rhymes with "coin" and "loin", and the sound of "OI" is the same as in "toy" and is definitely different than the long I in "find".

What is the explanation for this? It seems strange that the diphthong OI would have the same sound as I in find, even in a historical period. Was that indeed the case?

---

(Note: before suggesting the idea that Alexandrian poetry has non-rhyming couplets, consider this research. ALL of Pope's couplets are meant to rhyme. Pope's couplets are known in theory as heroic couplets, and it is a feature of this type of poetry that the couplets are composed of perfect rhymes. See "The Heroic Couplet" by William Bowman Piper (1969). If you have questions about a perfect rhyme, or some doubt that heroic couplets are composed of perfect rhymes, that is the book.)

Comment: The do rhyme in 21st century in some British accents – either way round, or should I say *rind*?

Comment: If what you say in your note is true, it is incontrovertible that the two words rhymed: no sane person can dispute it and there seems little point in the question. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597902/did-the-words-come-and-home-historically-rhyme/597904?noredirect=1#comment1504497_597904 may be of interest.

Comment: More to the point, was there anything like "received pronunciation" at the time? Because one can be reasonably sure that in some English dialects they rhymed, and in others they didn't.

Comment: @WeatherVane As schoolchildren in Yorkshire we discovered that even Shakespeare rhymes if read in a Northern accent.

Comment: In the [New York Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) they sometimes rhyme to this very day.

Comment: Can you say where it's written that words like those must always clearly match and the suggestion of closely mismatching is forbidden? Would that not deny the essence of poetry?

Comment: Worth noting that "join" is spelled "jine" a couple of times in _Treasure Island_, suggesting that this was a dialectical pronunciation.

Answer (score 21):

It's entirely possible that Pope rhymed *find* with *joined.* Pope attended Twyford School in Hampshire before his family moved to Berkshire.

There are still dialects of English where /ɔɪ/ is used where Standard English would use /aɪ/, making a word like *light* sound *loit.* Famous East Anglia example: [*Have you got a light, boy*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHe4tMN6IeE), although this would sound similar in a Sussex accent, and the phenomenon is even more noticeable further west.

Comment: Accent? Or just dropped the e from joined to fit the meter and rhyme? I can see it. That's a weak syllable anyway; easy to drop.

Comment: @Joshua Yes, *accent* as in **dialectal manner of pronunciation** not *accent* as in a stressed syllable.

Comment: Excellent answer in general, but the kind of East Anglia accent heard in the linked song doesn’t really illustrate it — their *light* is shifted closer to a standard English *loit*, but their *loit* is also shifted further onward, so these two diphthongs remain distinct, not merged.  In the song, for instance, their *boy* and *by* are clearly different, as heard in “When she sees me passing by”, [from around 1:00](https://youtu.be/PHe4tMN6IeE?t=60).

Answer (score 16):

They either rhymed or were very close near-rhymes.

The [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), which changed the quality of English long vowels, happened between 1400 and 1800. The vowel of *find*, *time*, and *price*, started in 1400 as [iː] (the vowel in *bead* today. According to the chart in the Wikipedia article, between 1600 and 1800 it first turned to /əi/, and then to /ʌi/, before reaching its modern value of /aɪ/ in the 19th century. Meanwhile, the vowel of *join* stayed roughly the same, /ɔɪ/.

The diphthongs /ʌi/ and /ɔɪ/ sound quite similar, and they are certainly close enough to be used as rhymes in poetry. Furthermore, while not everybody in England could have pronounced them the same (if they had, these vowels would presumably have stayed the same forever), it's certainly possible that some people did.

Isaac Watts (1674-1748), who lived around the same time as Pope (1688–1744) and wrote a large number of hymns and other poems, rhymed these two diphthongs as well:

> Lord, I am thine; but thou wilt prove
> My faith, my patience, and my love;
> When men of spite against me join,
> They are the sword, the hand is thine.

Watts did use a lot of near-rhymes, so you can't tell from his poems whether they were exact rhymes or merely very good near-rhymes for him.

One comment: Watts seems to rhyme these two vowels mainly when they come before /n/, so in early 18th century pronunciation, the sequences /ɔɪn/ and /aɪn/ were presumably better near-rhymes than, say, *noise* and *rise*.

Comment: I've seen this 'rhyme' in other 18th century verse too.

Comment: [oi] and [ai] are very close together. Both are diphthongs with high front offglide, and their starting positions are very close, down in the angle of the throat. It would be easy to rhyme them, just like it is to rhyme German _wissen_ with _schüssen_ in "Die Gedanken Sind Frei".

Comment: @JohnLawler [Noice.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BC9eaGQNFSM&feature=emb_logo)

Answer (score 3):

The most common explanation of this is that *join* had an unrounded diphthong at this time, /əi/ or /ʌi/.

This can be explained as a regular development from an earlier diphthong /ui/ (or /ʊi/); the first part of the diphthong unrounded (just as the short monophthong /u/ unrounded to /ʌ/ in words like *sun, nut, drunk*), causing it to merge with the vowel in words like *find,* which is assumed to have at some point gone through the steps /əi/ > /ʌi/ > /ai/.

The modern pronunciation of *join* with /ɔɪ/ would be either an alternative phonological development of /ui/, or a spelling pronunciation based on both original /ui/ and original /ɔɪ/ being spelled with the digraph *oi/oy.*

I'm not entirely sure how to tell whether a word spelled with *oi*/*oy* originally had /ui/ or /ɔɪ/, but some historical sources give lists, and I think it's related to the word's etymology in French.

For more details, see the links in my answer to [Does English have (or has it had) the diphthongs /uɪ, ʌɪ/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403858/77227)